The Events Calendar return the wrong start time
I created an event with the date 2024-06-18 and start_time 8:00am on the Time Zone Europe/Brussels. The wordpress is set on  Asia/Hong_Kong timezone.
if i get the start time like this
$event_timezone = Tribe__Events__Timezones::get_event_timezone_string($event_id);
var_dump(tribe_get_start_time($event_id, 'g:i A', $event_timezone));

I get the start date 12:00 AM
if i get it like this:
 $wp_timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
 var_dump(tribe_get_start_time($event_id, 'g:i A', $wp_timezone));

i get 6:00 AM
If i don't specify the timezone parameter i get 12:00 AM
why i'm not getting 8:00am ? what am I'm doing wrong?  is there a different field or what?
This does not make any sense. I disabled all the other plugin to take out of equation problems from other plugins.

we don't know how work the functions of the plugin "tribe" then you will have more help in asking the developers of this plugin.

i also posted on wordpress forum, no answer so far.

i checked the database and i found that the date tribe_get_start_time or the other one that is getting the day is using the meta _EventStartDateUTC and this must work perfect if your server is using utc timezone.
So I used _EventStartDate meta instead, this one is using the value from wordpress backend as far as I can see.
